# wordpress как в базе найти товар по метке?

Tags: wordpress

Делаю свой скрипт для выборки товара по метке (к вордпресс не подсоединен) но структуру базы понять не могу.. Есть метка в таблице wp_terms с id, и значением, но связи её с постом не нашел.. Ни в самом посте ни где либо еще.. Как это понять? они не связаны но работают как то вместе. Может кто то сталкивался и знает где эта связь зарыта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Процедура получения метки многоступенчатая.

Пост имеет свой id. В таблице `wp_term_relationships` надо найти записи с таким `object_id`, взять соответствующие `term_taxonomy_id`.

В таблице `wp_term_taxonomy` выбрать все записи с полученными на предыдущем шаге `term_taxonomy_id`. Проверить у полученных записей поле `taxonomy`. Если там строка `product_tag`, то это метка. Взять в этой записи поле `term-id`.

Найти в таблице `wp_terms` запись с таким `term-id`. Вот она - ваша метка!